# При нажатии на кнопку иногда не срабатывает удар в работе ближнего боя Unity

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Имеется скрипт для ближнего боя в 2д раннере, все вроде бы корректно написал и он даже работает,но как то коряво. При нажатии на кнопку иногда не срабатывает удар(ну это по моим наблюдениям, возможно там что то другое происходит).

Как это исправить?

```
 private bool isAttacking = false;
    private float attackTimer = 0f;
    private float attackReset = 0.2f;
    public GameObject attackPoint;
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        attackPoint.SetActive(false);
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && !isAttacking)
        {
            isAttacking = true;
            attackPoint.SetActive(true);
            attackTimer = attackReset;
            Reset();
        }
        else
        {
            isAttacking = false;
            attackPoint.SetActive(false);
            
        }
 
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        if (attackTimer > 0)
        {
            attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (attackTimer <= 0)
        {
            isAttacking = false;
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

У вас несколько странная логика, непонятно зачем вообще таймер, ведь после установки `isAttacking` в `true` следующий же вызов `Update` пойдёт в ветку `else` и всё сбросит. А следующий `Update` может произойти очень быстро.

Я не очень знаю как правильно в `Unity` всё делается, но чисто по логике я бы сделал такую логику:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if(!isAttacking)
        {
            isAttacking = true;
            attackPoint.SetActive(true);
            attackTimer = attackReset;
        }
        else
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isAttacking = false;
        attackPoint.SetActive(false);
        
    }
```

Я бы и название функции `Reset` поменял, это же не сброс (безусловный), это что-то типа `DecreaseAttackTimer`.

Хотя по-хорошему тут всё мне кажется нужно переписывать по-другому как-то.